# How to trigger the new twitter widget using JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter, widget

When loading content via ajax the new twitter widget doesn't trigger, I found a solution to this for the old widget using `$.getScript` but so far can't find a solution for the new widget (script grabs variables from an `<a>` tag and pass through to build content in an iFrame whereas the old one just used js variables). Does anyone have any ideas or a solution?

Many thanks

Justin

Comment: One way to examine an API's data structure is to type the API URL directly into your web browser and inspect the resulting JSON directly

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm a fool... I was over thinking it :-/
All it needs is the following:

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js')
```